# WMIC translation table

Tags: formatting, output, wmic

Where can I get documentation about translation tables, used in `WMIC` `/TRANSLATE` switch? As I have found, there are only two tables, shipped with `WMIC`: `BasicXml` and `NoComma`. How can I manage the tables: list them, view, add, delete, rename? Which format does they have? I suppose, when I use the tables, there are only single character replacing rules. Or some other rules may apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These translation tables come from `MSFT_CliTranslateTable` and `MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry` classes. Those are defined (and poorly documented) in `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\cli.mof` file.

```
…
[Abstract] 
class MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
{
  string FromValue;
  string ToValue;
};

class MSFT_CliTranslateTable
{
  [key] string Name;
  MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry Tbl[];
};
…
```

**Example** using `wmic`:

```
==> wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\cli PATH MSFT_CliTranslateTable get
Name                                                                                     
NoComma                                                                                  
              {}  2    MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry    MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry  2  ,  
BasicXml                                                                                 
              {}  2    MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry    MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry  2  &gt;  >
              {}  2    MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry    MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry  2  &lt;  <
```

**Another example** using `wmic`:

```
==> wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\cli PATH MSFT_CliTranslateTable get /Value | findstr "^$ Name __CLASS FromValue ToValue"

Name=NoComma

__CLASS=MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
FromValue=,
ToValue=

Name=BasicXml

__CLASS=MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
FromValue=&amp;gt;
ToValue=&gt;

__CLASS=MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
FromValue=&amp;lt;
ToValue=&lt;
```

**Extra example** using `powershell`:

```
PS D:\PShell> 
$comp      = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$namespace = "ROOT\Cli"
$classname = "MSFT_CliTranslateTable"

$instances = Get-WmiObject -Class $classname -ComputerName $comp -Namespace $namespace

$instances |
  ForEach-Object { $_ |
    Select-Object -Property @{N='RELPATH';     E={$_.__RELPATH}}, 
                            @{N='TrTableName'; E={$_.Name}} -ExpandProperty Tbl
  } | Format-Table -Property TrTableName, FromValue, ToValue, __CLASS #, RELPATH
```

**Output**:

> ```
> TrTableName FromValue ToValue __CLASS                    
> ----------- --------- ------- -------                    
> NoComma     ,                 MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
> BasicXml    &gt;      >       MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
> BasicXml    &lt;      <       MSFT_CliTranslateTableEntry
> ```